# Exit a method back to Main?

Tags: c#, methods, program-entry-point, exit

I'm learning C# and it's basically my first coding experience. I've created a Main "Menu" method that goes to other sub methods (some are voids, others bools and ints) with a switch and usage of :

```
Program Execute = new Program();
Execute.SubMethodName();
```

Which is working quite well for me, except that i can't exit the sub-method. I have searched over google, stack overflow and the msdn website and every time the answer was to use "return" but i have tried it and it just returns back to the sub-method. How can i exit the sub-methods back to my Main method ?

(Excuse me if i'm not very clear, i'm still learning and i'm very willing to rephrase myself)

Comment: Hard to tell without some idea of what `SubMethodName` does - one guess though - does it have a `while (true)` infinite loop in it somewhere (or else a `for` on an infinite series?)  If so, `break` is the keyword you are looking for.

Comment: It varies on the method "SubMethodName" is just a generic name i put there for clarity. Break doesn't work here, i've just tried. Maybe the way i'm coding this doesn't work ? I have my Main first calling other methods with the Execute function i created, and then my methods.

Comment: Can you post the code you've written for those methods?

Comment: Sure, here you are :
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Vq92IiTvS5NGH72kCvGpGX41vLZpeKXe6avPjG5X2AY/edit
Comments are in french though... (and a lot of it is still rough and needs more work, but i'm trying to get the structure to work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your `Exercice` functions wait for the user to press ENTER (you call `Console.ReadLine()`). So to exit, you need to press ENTER on the console screen.

Comment: I know, it's voluntary but when i do, the Exercice functions just re-execute themselves instead of going back to Main, no matter what i do (return, break, ENTER)

Comment: Then it's a problem with your main loop - the Console.ReadLine there returns something unexpected. You should use a debugger.

Comment: I didn't work. But i found an alternative, i just created a menu method that was directly called by my main, that my other methods called at the end of their execution. Thank you all.

Comment: A "it didn't work" reply is most often indicating a problem in the question, not the answer. People asked you to provide more details, yet all you did was to claim that "it didn't work". The latter is mostly a function of people not having a crystal ball to see what you refuse to tell them. Print that and hang it over your desk.